# Java logging API overhead

Tags: java, logging, conditional-compilation, overhead

I've read a bit about the various ways of logging a debugging message with Java, and coming from a C background my concern is as follow :

Those libraries claim minimal overhead in case where logging is disabled (such as production environment), but since argument to their `log()` function are still evaluated, my concern is that the overhead in real-world scenario will, in fact, not be negligible at all.

For example, a `log(myobject.toString(), "info message")` still has the overhead of evaluating `myobject.toString()`, which can be pretty big, even if the log function itself does nothing.

Does anyone has a solution to this issue ?

PS: for those wondering why I mentioned a C background : C lets you use preprocessor macro and compile-time instructions that will completely remove all the code related to debugging at compilation time, including macros parameters (which will simply not appear at all).

EDIT : 
After having read the first batch of answers, it seems that java clearly doesn't have anything that would do the trick (think logging the cosine of a number in a big loop in a mobile environment where every bit of CPU matters). So i'll add that i would even go for an IDE based solution. My last resort being building something like a "find all / replace" macro. 
I first thought that maybe something grabbed from an aspect oriented framework would help...
Anyone ?

Answer (score 9):

I think that [the log4j FAQ](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#a2.3) does a good job of addressing this:

> For some logger l, writing,
>
> ```
> l.debug("Entry number: " + i + " is " + String.valueOf(entry[i]));
> ```
>
> incurs the cost of constructing the message parameter, that is converting both integer i and entry[i] to a String, and concatenating intermediate strings. This, regardless of whether the message will be logged or not.
>
> If you are worried about speed, then write
>
> ```
>  if(l.isDebugEnabled()) {
>      l.debug("Entry number: " + i + " is " + String.valueOf(entry[i]));
>  }
> ```
>
> This way you will not incur the cost of parameter construction if debugging is disabled for logger l. On the other hand, if the logger is debug enabled, you will incur the cost of evaluating whether the logger is enabled or not, twice: once in debugEnabled and once in debug. This is an insignificant overhead since evaluating a logger takes less than 1% of the time it takes to actually log a statement.

Using a guard clause is the general approach to avoid string construction here.

Other popular frameworks, such as [slf4j](http://www.slf4j.org/), take the approach of [using formatted strings / parameterized messages](http://www.slf4j.org/faq.html#logging_performance) so that the message is not evaulated unless needed.

Comment: +1 for the last line. Parameterized arguments is always an option.

Comment: @Tim Bender, Provided you don't have any primitives.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.Parameterized messages doesn't suit me, because you sometimes need to build complex expression (such as computation), and i really don't want to do them in production environment. I'll wait a bit to see if anyone comes with a magic solution, because i still find it incredible that java doesn't have a way of doing it with no overhead at all...

Comment: How could it be done without any overhead, in any programming environment? An expression/variable needs to be resolved in order to be passed to a function. You could pass a function pointer, which seems extra elaborate. In Java you could accomplish this by passing an anonymous function that extends Object where the `toString()` returns the expression you'd like to (conditionally) log, but this would make your code extra ugly.

Comment: have a look at C preprocessor and macros, you'll be amazed. Also, look at my EDIT comment.

Answer (score 4):

Modern logging frameworks have variable replacement. Your logging then looks something like this:

```
log.debug("The value of my first object is %s and of my second object is %s", firstObject, secondObject).
```

The toString() of the given objects will then only be executed when logging is set to debug. Otherwise it will just ignore the parameters and return.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is pretty simple: don't call expensive methods in the log call itself. Plus, use guards around the logging call, if you can't avoid it.

```
 if(logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
    logger.debug("this is an "+expensive()+" log call.");
 }
```

And as others have pointed out, if you have formatting available in your logging framework (i.e., if you're using one modern enough to support it, which should be *every one of them* but isn't), you should rely on that to help defray expense at the point of logging. If your framework of choice does *not* support formatting already, then either switch or write your own wrapper.

Comment: I find this to be a workaround that messes up my code: why should I add 3 lines of code for a trivial log statement?

Comment: Then don't use it? I mean, hey, you make the choice of what logging framework to use, and how; I don't use guard statements myself because I *do* use a wrapper for logging if the underlying structure doesn't enable delayed evaluation of formatting statements.

Comment: Sorry if you felt that was an attack, I wasn't mean to be one. I just wanted to add that comment so that it's known that this is not a universally loved approach ;-)

Comment: Sure, NP. I didn't feel attacked; I was just echoing the party line (as written by Ceki Gulcu) about guard clauses. I don't really respect most of the logging frameworks, as they're really rather inflexible, and it's funny that Ceki - a nice guy, BTW - is now on his *fourth* attempt at writing a comprehensive logging framework.

Comment: Omit the braces and the 3 lines become one. Bind a shortcut/template in your IDE to automatically print the guard clause and start the log message off with the name of the current method, and then it just takes a few keystrokes.

Comment: Heh. That's an idea - but I personally wouldn't care about saving the line count. Blocks are useful! (And habitual, in my case.)

Comment: @matt: yes, I know, but my companies coding standards require blocks on `if`/`while`/... (and I agree with that!). Changing the standard just for log statements prevents tool support for those standards. All in all, I find the formatting solution to be more elegant (but judging from the votes I'm in a minority here).

Comment: @Joachim: not from me, at least. If I use logging frameworks (which I don't, normally), I'll use one that has formatting capabilities (hopefully matching printf's syntax) or write my own wrappers. But then again: logging, ew. It's like caches: once you start using them, you're really compensating for a flaw that shouldn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

You're right, evaluating the arguments to a `log()` call **can** add overhead that is unnecessary and *could* be expensive.

That's why most sane logging frameworks provide some string formatting functions as well, so that you can write stuff like this:

```
log.debug("Frobnicating {0}", objectWithExpensiveToString);
```

This way your **only** overhead is the call to `debug()`. If that level is deactivated, then nothing more is done and if it is activated, then the format string is interpreted, the `toString()` on `objectWithExpensiveToString()` is called and the result inserted into the format string before it is logged.

Some log statements use [`MessageFormat`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html) style placeholders (`{0}`), others use [`format()` style](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) placeholders (`%s`) and yet others might take a third approach.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a funny way - a bit verbose, though - with assertions. With assertions turned on, there will be output and overhead, and with assertions turned off, no output and absolutely no overhead.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    assert returnsTrue(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // your logging code
        }
    });
}

public static boolean returnsTrue(Runnable r) {
    r.run();
    return true;
}
```

The returnsTrue() function is needed here because I know no better way of making an expression return true, and assert requires a boolean.

Comment: `assert` doesn't *need* the parenthesis and I'd argue that it's cleaner without. Because this way it looks like a method call which it is not.